Не могу найти утечку памяти javascript pdf.js
Я сократил код до "минимума", где проявляется данная проблема. На файлах с большим количеством элементов (таблицы, надписи и прочее. главное что не просто скан документа), код потребляет подозрительно много озу (накапливается по выполнению цикла for, когда идут такого рода страницы). через секунд 10 после окончания оно очищается.
собственно сам код:
"use strict";


pdfInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
    fileHandler(this.files);
})


async function fileHandler(files) {
    // pdf parsing
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(fileURL).promise;
    const numPages = pdf.numPages;
    console.log("");
    console.log('Pages: ' + numPages);
    
    for (let numPage = 0; numPage < numPages; numPage++) {
        const page = await pdf.getPage(numPage + 1);

        // transform page to image
        const viewport = page.getViewport({scale: 0.5});
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const renderContext = {canvasContext: ctx, viewport: viewport};
        await page.render(renderContext).promise;
        await page.cleanup();
    }
    pdf.cleanup();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
    files = null;

    console.log("finish");
};

так файл на 59мб (157 страниц) потребляет около 250мб (что тоже как-то многовато), а файл на 17мб (51 страница), где есть несколько таких нагруженных страниц потребляет около 450мб
Буду очень рад, если поможете. Сам я сколько не искал, найти не смог

¿Что видно в профилировщике памяти?

Если память очищается, значит утечки нет. Сбор мусора выполняется раз в n времени во время "простоя".

@SwaD, а можно как-то самим очистить? Что бы не накапливать и авось оно когда-нибудь сделается, а сразу. И там по-моему не всё очищается. Много, но не всё

@user7860670, в смысле снимок кучи сделать? Или где его искать? Простите, сам не знаю)

Не думаю, что браузер разрешит вам управлять сбором мусора. Ну и в целом, для современных пк, росто памяти до 450мб - явно не проблема. Отдельно можно попробовать код растащить на мелкие независимые функции, может часть обработки отдать бэку или, допустим, вэбворкеру. Тут конечно надо замерять, какая из операций больше всех поедает озу. Попробуйте избавиться от создания лишних переменных, если таковые есть.

@SwaD, ну на этом файле 450, а если этот файл будет большой, там до 3гб не далеко) С переменными как ни возись всё одно. У меня был такой же эффект только в большей степени пока я не добавил page.cleanup(), а дальше никакой объект я очистить не смог, что бы что-то поменялось. Web worker скоро собираюсь начать использовать, но хотел перед этим добить память
